# Upgrading Guzzle from old version to new version

Tags: php, composer-php, guzzle

I have project which has an old version of Guzzle Installed

```
"guzzle/guzzle": "3.9"
```

But the guzzle developers changed the package to

```
"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~6.0"
```

I mean they changed the version to new version but they even changed how the composer should install it like before it was `composer require guzzle/guzzle` but now it is "`composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle"`
I just want to know that will it affect my code if remove my old guzzle and install new "`guzzlehttp/guzzle`" because all of code is based on the old guzzle version.

Comment: Yes, that affects your code. There are tons of changes between v3.9 (which is more than six years old!) and a current version of Guzzle. But I hope the internal test suite of your application is broad enough to help you adjust your code

Comment: Thanx for the info @Nico, I guess i will be doing the upgrade in the weekend so that even if something breaks, it doesn't affect that much on the live site.